# Is there a typeparam for c# file?

Tags: blazor

Is there a C# equivalent to the @typeparam?  I can't find anything in documentation.

```
@typeparam T

<div>@typeof(T).Name</div>

@code {
    [TypeParameter] type T {get;set;}  //does not work
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a specific [TypeParameter] annotation as far as I'm aware. There also doesn't really need to be: @typeparam arranges it for you and still allows you to set it as a parameter. You can ofcourse change T to be a bit more descriptive and you can use multiple ones.

That does mean that if you place your code in a codebehind file, you need to both the .razor and the .cs to match in terms of generic. So:

### .razor

```
@typeparam T
<div>@typeof(T).Name</div>
```

### .cs

```
public partial class ExampleComponent<T>
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing!